# populate list item with data from a mysql table google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

In google apps script is there a way to populate list item with data from a mysql table. I wrote my function but I get undefined in the dropdown list. Could you please point me where I am doing it wrong.

```
    function readFormListFromTable() {
var address = 'database_IP_address';
var user = 'user_name';
var userPwd = 'user_password';
var db = 'database_name';
var dbUrl = 'jdbc:mysql://' + address + '/' + db;
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  var results = stmt.executeQuery('SELECT [name] FROM employee');
  var numCols = results.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
  while (results.next()) {
    var rowString = '';
    for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
      rowString += results.getString(col + 1) + '\t';
    }
  }
  results.close();
  stmt.close();
var form = FormApp.openById('42udfksdfksukdnf-DWER');
var tablelistitem = form.addListItem();        
tablelistitem.setTitle('Name from mysql table')
                   .setChoices([tablelistitem.createChoice(rowString)]);   
}
```

Comment: You can try to check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc) about External Databases in Google Apps Script. Apps Script can connect to external databases through the JDBC service, a wrapper around the standard Java Database Connectivity technology. In Apps Script, the JDBC service supports Google Cloud SQL, MySQL, Microsoft SQL Server, and Oracle databases. Just check the above link for the [sample code](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc#sample_code) on how to setup and create database also how to write and read from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We develop the next script into a Form and configure a tigger on open, to populate a dropdown list and its working. I hope this code help you :

```
function onOpen(){
var conexion=conectar_mysql(); //realizo conexion con mysql
var tiposHora=getTiposHora(conexion); //genero una lista con los tipos de hora disponibles
var form = FormApp.openById('form_id');
var item = form.addListItem(); // lista de todos los elementos que pertenecen al formulario para recargar el que me interese
item.setTitle('Tipos de Horas')
item.setChoiceValues(tiposHora);//recarga con los valores que necesito
```

}

```
function getTiposHora(conexion){
 var stmt = conexion.createStatement();
 var results = stmt.executeQuery('SELECT tipo FROM bbdd.tabla;');
 var numCols = results.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
 var tiposDeHora=[];
 while (results.next()) {
     var rowString = '';
     for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
          rowString += results.getString(col + 1) + '\t';
          tiposDeHora.push(rowString);
     }
 }
 return tiposDeHora;
```

}

```
function conectar_mysql(){

 var address = 'direccion';
 var user = 'usuario';
 var userPwd = 'password';
 var db = 'bbdd';
 var instanceUrl = 'jdbc:mysql://' + address;
 var dbUrl = instanceUrl + '/' + db;
 var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);
 conn.setAutoCommit(false);
 return conn;
```

}